# Cannot edit my config.inc.php file on macOS mojave, dowloaded XAMPP

Tags: php, macos, xampp

I have read every question that tried to fix this and none of the solutions have worked. If i try to edit the file using sudo nano `config.inc.php` i get the following error:

> Error writing config.inc.php: Permission denied

This post is pretty much the same issues I'm having, for more info the user has 
a more detailed explanation in the comments:
[PHPhelp](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHPhelp/comments/8z5wvd/beginner_mac_changed_root_password_on_phpmyadmin/)

There was no solution there either, sorry to have to ask another one of these but i've spent 3 hrs no joke trying to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

On the `CMD` type:

chmod 755 config.inc.php
   chown :wheel config.inc.php

**NOTE:** If you are not opening the command line on the same folder as your file you will need to map the system to the file